# Configure varnish for invalidating cache based on url, and authorization header

Tags: varnish

I was wondering if it was possible to invalidate cached object by url.

Say i have the url /api/0.1/user and the url /api/0.1/userFriends what i´d like to know, is if there is a way to make /api/0.1/user invalidated when a PUT request to /api/0.1/userMedia is made. However it should only invalidate cache by the http header Authorization. so basically only invalidate cache for the user which performed the PUT request.

I reckon i need a ban configuration to make this work, but im fairly new to varnish, so an example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible. If you have something like this in vcl_recv:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.request == "PUT") {
    http.req.x-url = regsub(req.url, "(/api/0.1/user)Media", "\1");
    ban_url("^" + x-url);
    unset req.http.x-url;
  }
}
```

This is completely untested. "man vcl" for more info on vcl syntax and semantics.